# Else if statement with length won run even though console log recognizes it

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

This code doesn't run the else if part at all even though i did console.log and it recognizes 0 length too. It still won't show the string. It will give the first parth though. What is the problem?

```
function check_width() {

    var width= $('#plwidth').val();

    if (width< 20 || width> 200) {
      $('#error_width').html("Annettu luku ei kelpaa");
      $('#error_width').show();
    } else if (width.length === 0) {
      $('#error_width').html("T&auml;yt&auml; kentt&auml;");
      $('#error_width').show();
    } else {
      $('#error_leveys').hide();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of width while you are executing this function?

Comment: What I'm trying is to have form input empty and run the string below the length === 0 part. This code runs when it focuses out of the input.

Comment: If `width.length===0` then `width<20` also (ie `""<20 === true`) - so it always runs the first part - it will never hit the middle section ("Tata").

Comment: @freedomn-m how should i fix this?

Comment: `var width = +$('#plwidth').val();` `+` will convert the string to int

Comment: @ManosKounelakis that will also convert `""` to `0` so will have the same issue (hit the `width<0` first) and add the problem that you can't check for empty input.   Depends on the use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the problem

The problem is that `$("input").val()` will always be a string.  When you compare a string with a number (using `==` or `<` etc) then javascript will apply automatic type conversion - ie convert the string to an int.  Where it can't do this, it will return a zero.

So if your input is empty instead of a number then

```
"" < 20 == true 
0 < 20 == true
```

so it calls your first line and never gets to the `width.length == 0` check.

In this case, it seems the simplest solution is to check for an empty input first, ie:

```
function check_width() {

    var width= $('#plwidth').val();

    if (width.length === 0) {
      $('#error_width').html("T&auml;yt&auml; kentt&auml;");
      $('#error_width').show();
    } else if (width < 20 || width > 200) {
      $('#error_width').html("Annettu luku ei kelpaa");
      $('#error_width').show();
    } else {
      $('#error_width').html("").hide()
      //$('#error_leveys').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`width.length` seems to be incorrect and there is no `length` property unless it is a string or array

Replace `else if (width.length === 0) {` with `else if (width === 0) {`

Comment: What I'm trying is to have form input empty and run the string below the length === 0 part. This code runs when it focuses out of the input. So I guess that wouldn't work for my purpose. Thanks though!

Comment: can you please create a demo

Comment: `$('#plwidth').val()` *will* always be a string, so will have `length` property and javascript will apply automatic type conversion when comparing a string with a number